Same Admin user to be able to switch the tenants on OAuth page to install the MS Teams bot
I have built an MS Teams bot using the botbuilder JS framework. I've created an admin user in tenant A and the bot was authorized to get the required permissions and be installed in the tenant on behalf of the whole organization using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&state=<state>&prompt=select_account, params are configured in the Azure App registration for that app.
Now, I have invited that admin user to a different tenant B and assigned the Global Administrator role where I want to install the same bot. So, when I use the above adminconsent URL from my app and get redirected to the OAuth page to grant permissions, I do not see an option to switch the original tenant A to tenant B where I want to install the bot. I couldn't find how to do so in the documentation anywhere.
However, I could install the bot in the tenant B using https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/adminconsent?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&state=<state>&prompt=select_account where I manually added tenant_id of the tenant B in the URL instead of common
Please note that Supported Account Types in the Azure portal for that app is set to Multiple organizations, so it could be installed to multiple tenants.
Any leads in this direction will be appreciated. Thank you!

Could you please look into this document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/multi-tenant/manage?view=o365-worldwide
Are you looking for the same?

@Sayali-MSFT I went through this document but couldn't find the 'All Tenants' page in the given MS 365 Admin center link, even though I invited my admin user from tenant A to a different tenant B and assigned Global Administrator privileges there.
I specifically wanted to switch the tenants while asking for admin consent for permissions and later on using the install app API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request to install the app.

@Sayali-MSFT if you meant I have to follow this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/set-up-multi-tenant-org?view=o365-worldwide to create a multi-tenant organization first, I couldn't find this option to do so in my MS 365 admin page

@Sayali-MSFT nudging you here

,Which option you did not find?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/oTWEcVpA.png
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/7ATrzu0e.png

@Sayali-MSFT Yeah this Multitenant Collaboration option in the 365 admin center, it seems like I don't have the required licenses. Though, I wanted to ask the question: Is it possible to switch the tenants on the Oauth page, if the admin user belongs to multiple tenants with Global administrator privilege? (for context, you can read the original question again?)

Yes, it is possible for an admin user who belongs to multiple tenants with Global Administrator privileges to switch tenants on the OAuth page. This can be achieved by configuring your application to support multi-tenant authentication in Azure AD. When an admin user logs in, they will be prompted to select the tenant they want to authenticate with if they belong to multiple tenants. The authority parameter set to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common allows users to authenticate with any Azure AD tenant.

Doc Link-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

@Sayali-MSFT  thanks for the answer. The doc link that you shared is not about switching the tenants on the OAuth page for granting permissions to an app, it is more about configuring the app in the app registration to be able to install that app into multiple tenants.
I couldn't find any doc about how that OAuth page shows an option to switch tenants to install the app if the user is an admin in both tenants. Do you mind sharing a screenshot or a doc link where it is shown?
